# Sony Bravia websocket support?

Tags: websocket, opera, sony, television, opera-presto

Our webapp uses websockets. 
When the page loads, we check for websocket support using:

```
if ('WebSocket' in window)
```

When we run the webapp on the Opera TV 3.4 emulator, we detect that websockets are available. 
When we run the webapp on a Sony Bravia KDL-50W829B, the websocket test fails.

Comparing the UserAgents, the Bravia KDL-50W829B version exceeds that of the emulator so we're expecting websockets to be available:

- 3.4 emulator: Opera/9.80 (Linux i686; Opera TV Store/5449) Presto/2.12.362 Version/12.10
- Bravia KDL-50W829B: Opera/9.80 (Linux
  armv7l; InettvBrowser/2.2 (00014A;SonyDTV140;0001;0001) KDL50W829B;
  CC/GBR) Presto/2.12.407 Version/12.50

According to these links, websockets should be available and enabled:

- http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.12/apis/#websocket
- https://dev.opera.com/blog/a-hot-opera-12-50-summer-time-snapshot/

We've also found other posts where it's mentioned that websockets don't work on the Bravia browser (search for lavag.org viewing panel via smart tv)

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: We've updated to support SockJS (uses other mechanisms when websockets aren't available) and our app works on the Sony Bravia now.  
Still interested in finding out why websockets aren't available though

Answer (score 0):

outside the normal browser ... say from inside a web worker this works

```
if (! ("WebSocket" in self)) {

    throw new Error("ERROR - websocket not available");
}
```

Comment: The websocket support detection we're using is working.  
The question is why websockets are available in the emulator but not when we use the real device